# Mobile automation tool for Windows

Tags: windows-phone-7, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using Appium & Robotium to automate Android & iOS application, but now I want to automate Windows mobile app. I searched a lot, but end up with some web-based tool. Currently, I searching  tool like Appium & Robotium (open source).

Are there any open source mobile automation tools for Windows mobile app?

Comment: this is a good, legitimate question. downvoters: either edit the question to improve it or add comments explaining the downvotes...

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to take a look at **[Winium.StoreApps](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps)** framework. 
It works very similar to Appium and enables to automate Windows Phone applications.

- [Test examples & documentation](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps/wiki)

Comment: does it need source code modification of App under test?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is the only reliable way [Coded-UI Test Project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/05/using-coded-ui-to-test-xaml-based-windows-phone-apps.aspx)

But there is a framework called [Expensify](https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework)- but works good only on wp7.